# Дробная часть

Tags: sql, plsql, запрос

Мне в запросе (pl/sql) необходимо отфильтровать только значения с дробной частью. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where ...
    and (value > floor(value) -- для положительных
        or (value < 0 and value < ceil(value)) -- для отрицательных
    )
```

В зависимости от значений в колонке, второе условие может не понадобиться.

Comment: Да и вне зависимости от значений тоже.

Comment: @alexlz, упрёк или подтверждение? :-) Просто если значения в колонке положительные (суммы какие-нибудь), то анализировать отрицательные смысла нет. А если есть, то `floor` уже не подходит&nbsp;&mdash; нужен `ceil`.

Comment: @orkaan почему floor не подходит для отрицательных чисел?

Comment: @alexlz, **спасибо** за настойчивость. ;)

    floor(5.9) -- would return 5
    floor(34.29) -- would return 34
    floor(-5.9) -- would return -6

Поэтому, действительно условия `value > floor(value)` будет достаточно.

Comment: @orkaan Пожалуйста, носите на здоровье.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать что-то вот такое:

```
SELECT SomeField
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeField - ROUND(SomeField) != 0
```

Попахивает какой-то костыльностью, но, думаю, вполне может сгодиться

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, например,

```
WHERE Ceil(val) != Floor(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так

```
where t.a_value - trunc(t.a_value) > 0
```

Или так

```
where mod(t.a_value,1) > 0
```